# A number in the ORDER BY

Tags: oracle

In the `ORDER BY` clause, what impact does '5' have on the whole query output? I thought `ORDER BY` could only work in relations with `DESC` or `ASC`.

```sql
SELECT
employee_id,
first_name,
last_name,
hire_date,
salary
FROM
employees
WHERE
(salary * 1.5) < 15000
ORDER BY
hire_date, 5;
```

Comment: Which learning material do you use to prepare for this exam?

Answer (score 4):

A number 'n' in the `ORDER BY` clause refers to the nth field in your `SELECT` clause.

In your example, number 5 refers to the `salary` column in the `SELECT`. It will therefore order by `hire_date` first, then on `salary` second.